# I have updated my xcode to 4.6 and now my app does not run on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have updated my xCode to 4.6, and now whenever I create new project and try to run it on my device which have iOS 5.1 then it will display error `CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.1'`. I have downloaded SDK's for iOs 6.1, 6.0, 5.0, 5.1, in my old version I can run any app without doing code signing in my device. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the bundle identifier in the **plist** and code sign identity

Comment: But, i have not created code signing identities for this project,actually i am using sample project from github,so its have its own bundle identifier and also what do you want me to check in plist,i can not alter its bundle identifier

Comment: You can alter the identifier.  do like this select the project in the Xcode and then select the target .Then you can find the info tab. There you can find the bundle identifier ,mention the old project identifier and then go to build settings tab. There is a row called Code Sign Identity. There select the provisioning profile. Then run it. Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: why is there necessary to create provisioning in every app in xcode 4.6,and not in previous version ,do you know?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24952/discussion-between-user247-and-aron)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step to successfully run your application  on your device:

- Make sure you or your organization have enrolled itself in apple iOS development program
- Check if you have a valid certificate installed in your keychain (if not create and install one [Certificate Utility](http://rx-games.com/creating-apple-development-and-distribution-certificates-explained/))
- Now [create provisioning profile](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-an-apple-development-provisioning-pr.html)
- Download them and install both by dragging them to your Xcode
- Now in build setting set code signing Identity by selecting these in [image: Code signing section]
- Now connect your device and run.

Here are some ados:

1. You might have certificate and provisioning already install in your pervious version so you didn't needed to set them again
2. Set the **Deployment target** [image] for your project as your device still have 5.1
3. And do what user247 suggested, i.e. set bunderIdentifier in info.plist file